# Linux setxattr: possible to use Unicode string?

Tags: linux, unicode, file-attributes, xattr

I wrote the following code in VS Code and ran it to set file attribute. It seemed to have run successfully, but when I checked the value, the text was not correct. Is Unicode string supported for file extended attributes? If so, how can I fix the code below?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/xattr.h>

int main()
{
    printf("ねこ\n");
    ssize_t res = setxattr("/mnt/cat/test.txt", "user.dog"
    , "ねこ", 2, 0); /*also tested 4 and 8*/
    printf("Result = %lu\n", (unsigned long)res);
    return 0;    
}
```

Programme output

```
ねこ
Result = 0
```

Reading attribute

```
$ getfattr test.txt  -d
# file: test.txt
user.dog=0s44E=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously `ねこ` can't be stored in 2 bytes. The characters are U+306D and U+3053, encoded in UTF-8 as `E3 81 AD E3 81 93` so length must be set to 6. If you did that you'll see that `getfattr test.txt -d` outputs

```
user.dog=0s44Gt44GT
```

That's because `-d` doesn't what format the data is in and just dumps it as binary. The `0s` prefix means that the data is in base64 as stated from the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getfattr.1.html):

> - `-d`, `--dump`
>
>   - Dump the values of all matched extended attributes.
> - `-e en`, `--encoding=en`
>
>   - Encode values after retrieving them. Valid values of en are "text", "hex", and "base64". Values encoded as text strings are enclosed in double quotes ("), while **strings encoded as hexidecimal and base64 are prefixed with 0x and 0s**, respectively.

Just plug `44Gt44GT` into any base64 decoder or run `echo 44Gt44GT | base64 --decode` and you'll see the correct string printed out. To see the string directly from `getfattr` you need to specify the format with `-e text`

```
$ getfattr -n user.dog -e text test.txt
# file: test.txt
user.dog="ねこ"
```